# Get print job's color/monochrome setting from its device context

Tags: c++, winapi, printing, gdi

Given a handle to a device context (or information context) for a printer, how can I determine whether printing will be in color or not?

Here's a reduced repro of the situation:

```
#include <Windows.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    // Find the default printer.
    DWORD cchName = 0;
    ::GetDefaultPrinterW(nullptr, &cchName);
    std::wstring name(cchName, L'\0');
    ::GetDefaultPrinterW(name.data(), &cchName);

    // Is it a color printer?
    const bool color_printer =
        ::DeviceCapabilitiesW(name.c_str(), nullptr, DC_COLORDEVICE, nullptr,
                              nullptr) != 0;
    if (color_printer) {
        std::cout << "DeviceCapabilities says it's a color printer.\n";
    } else {
        return 0;  // this case is not interesting for us.
    }

    // Open the printer and get its default DEVMODE.
    HANDLE hPrinter = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    PRINTER_DEFAULTSW defaults = {nullptr, nullptr, PRINTER_ACCESS_USE};
    ::OpenPrinterW(name.data(), &hPrinter, &defaults);
    const auto cbNeeded =
        ::DocumentPropertiesW(NULL, hPrinter, name.data(), nullptr, nullptr,
                              0);
    std::vector<BYTE> buffer(cbNeeded, static_cast<BYTE>(0));
    auto *pdmDefault = reinterpret_cast<DEVMODEW *>(buffer.data());
    ::DocumentPropertiesW(NULL, hPrinter, name.data(), pdmDefault, nullptr,
                          DM_OUT_BUFFER);

    if (pdmDefault->dmFields & DM_COLOR) {
        std::cout << "Default DEVMODE says we can select color/monochrome.\n";
        if (pdmDefault->dmColor == DMCOLOR_COLOR) {
            std::cout << "Default DEVMODE says it's set to color.\n";
        }
    } else {
        std::cout << "DEVMODE cannot select between color and mono.\n";
        return 0;
    }

    std::cout << "Making a monochrome DEVMODE.\n";
    std::vector<byte> bufferMono = buffer;
    auto *pdmMono = reinterpret_cast<DEVMODEW *>(bufferMono.data());
    pdmMono->dmColor = DMCOLOR_MONOCHROME;
    // Let the driver validate our monochrome devmode.
    ::DocumentPropertiesW(NULL, hPrinter, name.data(), pdmMono, pdmMono,
                          DM_OUT_BUFFER | DM_IN_BUFFER);


    // With our monochrome DEVMODE, ask again whether it's a color printer.
    const bool will_do_color =
        ::DeviceCapabilities(name.c_str(), nullptr, DC_COLORDEVICE, nullptr,
                             pdmMono) != 0;
    if (will_do_color) {
        std::cout << "With mono DEVMODE, DeviceCapabilities says color!\n";
    }

    // Let's try an IC created with our mono DEVMODE.
    HDC hicPrinter = ::CreateICW(nullptr, name.c_str(), nullptr, pdmMono);
    const auto bppIC = ::GetDeviceCaps(hicPrinter, BITSPIXEL);
    std::cout << "GetDeviceCaps on IC says " << bppIC << " bits per pixel.\n";
    ::DeleteDC(hicPrinter);

    // How about with a true DC?
    HDC hdcPrinter = ::CreateDCW(nullptr, name.c_str(), nullptr, pdmMono);
    const auto bppDC = ::GetDeviceCaps(hdcPrinter, BITSPIXEL);
    std::cout << "GetDeviceCaps on DC says " << bppDC << " bits per pixel.\n";

#ifdef PRINT_SAMPLE
    DOCINFOW docinfo = {sizeof(docinfo), L"Test", nullptr, nullptr, 0};
    ::StartDocW(hdcPrinter, &docinfo);
    ::StartPage(hdcPrinter);
    ::SetTextColor(hdcPrinter, RGB(0x00, 0x99, 0x00));
    const std::wstring text = L"This green text should print as gray.";
    const auto cchText = static_cast<int>(text.size());
    ::TextOutW(hdcPrinter, 300, 300, text.c_str(), cchText);
    ::EndPage(hdcPrinter);
    ::EndDoc(hdcPrinter);
#endif

    ::DeleteDC(hdcPrinter);
    ::ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
    return 0;
}
```

I haven't found a way to determine whether the device is in monochrome mode from the DC itself.  Do I have to keep track of the dmColor field in the DEVMODE?

**Edited** Updated code sample for clarity and to show that DeviceCapabilities always says whether the printer *can* print color, regardless of the DEVMODE specified.

Comment: According to [Retrieving Device Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/retrieving-device-data), you can use ***GetDeviceCaps*** to retrieve device color data with a device context and ***DeviceCapabilities*** with name instead of your code.

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT:  Thanks.  What you said is true, but it's not reliable.  The code sample shows that if I ask a color printer to print in monochrome, GetDeviceCaps still indicates it's a color device.  Maybe that's a driver bug for my particular printer, but it's a very common model from a major manufacturer.  I'll update the code sample to show that DeviceCapabilities always says what the printer _can_ do, even if I specify a non-color DEVMODE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I found was to keep a copy of the DEVMODE used when the device context was created or last reset.

If the DEVMODE's dmFields bitmask contains DM_COLOR then you can check the dmColor member for DMCOLOR_COLOR or DMCOLOR_MONOCHROME.

If the DM_COLOR bit is not set, then you can query DeviceCapabilities for DC_COLORDEVICE.  If that returns non-zero then the printer is capable of color, and since the DEVMODE isn't forcing it to monochrome, it's a good guess that it's in a color mode.  Otherwise, it seems safe to assume the output would be monochrome.

It's a shame that there doesn't seem to be a query using GetDeviceCaps on the HDC to determine this.